# How to run FreeRTOS on TM4C129EXL?

Tags: c, http, freertos, texas-instruments, coap

I am working on a C project for the university where a CoAP server is to be hosted on a TM4C129EXL. It is particularly important to choose a FreeRTOS operating system. Unfortunately, I had to learn that Texas Instruments has stopped supporting FreeRTOS. There are no options for me to switch to another operating system. It is for this reason that I turn to you.

I'm looking for a sample program in which Free RTOS is executed on a TM4C129EXL board. In the best case, I would be happy about a Code Composer Studio Project, as this is the IDE we work with from the university.

If you do not have any sample code available, I would be happy to receive any other information regarding FreeRTOS and CoAP of course with reference to the TM4C129EXL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not specify if you had any requirements in terms of `FreeRTOS` version, but you can either:

- use the demo provided in file `SW-EK-TM4C1294XL-2.1.4.178.exe` available on [TI WEB](https://software-dl.ti.com/tiva-c/SW-EK-TM4C1294XL/latest/index_FDS.html) site as is - you will find it in directory `examples\boards\ek-tm4c1294xl-boostxl-senshub\senshub_iot`
- use this example as a basis to use a more recent version of FreeRTOS: you just would have to replace FreeRTOS source code by the most recent one, and maybe to modify some code in the demo: some function names/signatures may have changed across major versions.

The procedure hereafter describes step by step how to create a minimalist FreeRTOS program with Code Composer Studio 10.3.0 and FreeRTOS v202104.00 in a Windows 10 environment using the second approach. You may have to adjust the drive letter to you specific setup, I am using `D`: for the purpose of this example..

- Download [Code Composer Studio 10.3.0](https://www.ti.com/tool/CCSTUDIO), [FreeRTOS v202104.00](https://github.com/FreeRTOS/FreeRTOS/releases/download/202104.00/FreeRTOSv202104.00.zip) and [SW-EK-TM4C1294XL-2.1.4.178.exe](https://software-dl.ti.com/tiva-c/SW-EK-TM4C1294XL/latest/index_FDS.html).
- Install Code Composer Studio with support for the `Tiva-C` MCU familly. When prompted for a workspace name, specify `D:\ti\workspace_v10`.
- Unzip `FreeRTOSv202104.00.zip`into `D:\`.
- Unzip `SW-EK-TM4C1294XL-2.1.4.178.exe` into `D:\SW-EK-TM4C1294XL-2.1.4.178`.
- Launch CCS
- Use the menu item `File/New/CCS Project`, and create an 'Empty Project (with main.c).

[[image: Project creation wizzard]]

- Click on the `Finish`button.
- Create the following directories: 
  `D:\ti\workspace_v10\TM4C129EXL-FreeRTOS\driverlib`
   `D:\ti\workspace_v10\TM4C129EXL-FreeRTOS\inc`
   `D:\ti\workspace_v10\TM4C129EXL-FreeRTOS\FreeRTOS-Kernel`
   `D:\ti\workspace_v10\TM4C129EXL-FreeRTOS\FreeRTOS-Kernel\include`
   `D:\ti\workspace_v10\TM4C129EXL-FreeRTOS\FreeRTOS-Kernel\portable\GCC`
   `D:\ti\workspace_v10\TM4C129EXL-FreeRTOS\FreeRTOS-Kernel\portable\GCC\ARM_CM4F`
   `D:\ti\workspace_v10\TM4C129EXL-FreeRTOS\FreeRTOS-Kernel\portable\MemMang`
- Copy `D:\SW-EK-TM4C1294XL-2.1.4.178\examples\boards\ek-tm4c1294xl-boostxl-senshub\senshub_iot\FreeRTOSConfig.h` into `D:\ti\workspace_v10\TM4C129EXL-FreeRTOS`
- Copy all `.h` files from `D:\SW-EK-TM4C1294XL-2.1.4.178\driverlib` into `D:\ti\workspace_v10\TM4C129EXL-FreeRTOS\driverlib`.
- Copy `D:\SW-EK-TM4C1294XL-2.1.4.178\driverlib\gcc\libdriver.a` into `D:\ti\workspace_v10\TM4C129EXL-FreeRTOS\driverlib`.
- Copy all `.h`files from `D:\SW-EK-TM4C1294XL-2.1.4.178\inc` into `D:\ti\workspace_v10\TM4C129EXL-FreeRTOS\inc`.
- Copy all files present in `D:\FreeRTOSv202104.00\FreeRTOS\Source\include` into `D:\ti\workspace_v10\TM4C129EXL-FreeRTOS\FreeRTOS-Kernel\include`.
- Copy all `.c`files present in `D:\FreeRTOSv202104.00\FreeRTOS\Source` into `D:\ti\workspace_v10\TM4C129EXL-FreeRTOS\FreeRTOS-Kernel`.
- Copy all file present in `D:\FreeRTOSv202104.00\FreeRTOS\Source\portable\GCC\ARM_CM4F` into `D:\ti\workspace_v10\TM4C129EXL-FreeRTOS\FreeRTOS-Kernel\portable\GCC\ARM_CM4F`
- Copy `D:\FreeRTOSv202104.00\FreeRTOS\Source\portable\MemMang\heap_4.c` into `D:\ti\workspace_v10\TM4C129EXL-FreeRTOS\FreeRTOS-Kernel\portable\MemMang`.
- Edit `D:\ti\workspace_v10\TM4C129EXL-FreeRTOS\main.c`, and replace its content by:

```c
#include "FreeRTOS.h"
#include "task.h"

extern void prvSetupHardware();
extern void main_blinky();

int main(void)
{
    /* Configure the hardware ready to run the demo. */
    prvSetupHardware();

    main_blinky();

    /* Don't expect to reach here. */
    return 0;
}

void vApplicationStackOverflowHook( TaskHandle_t xTask, char *pcTaskName)
{
    while(1)
    {
    }
}
```

- Create a new file named `D:\ti\workspace_v10\TM4C129EXL-FreeRTOS\blinky.c` with the following content:

```c
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include "inc/hw_memmap.h"
#include "inc/hw_types.h"
#include "inc/hw_ints.h"
#include "driverlib/debug.h"
#include "driverlib/gpio.h"
#include "driverlib/sysctl.h"
#include "FreeRTOS.h"
#include "task.h"
#include "sysctl.h"

static void prvLedToggleTask();

/* Priorities at which the tasks are created. */
#define mainTOGGLE_LED_PRIORITY         ( tskIDLE_PRIORITY + 1 )
#define TOGGLE_LED_DELAY_MS             200

void main_blinky()
{
    /* create task */
    xTaskCreate( prvLedToggleTask, "LED", configMINIMAL_STACK_SIZE, NULL, mainTOGGLE_LED_PRIORITY, NULL );

    /* Start the tasks and timer running. */
    vTaskStartScheduler();

}

static void prvLedToggleTask( void *pvParameters )
{
    // Remove compiler warning about unused parameter. */
    ( void ) pvParameters;

    for( ;; )
    {
        //
        // Turn on the LED.
        //
        GPIOPinWrite(GPIO_PORTN_BASE, GPIO_PIN_0, GPIO_PIN_0);

        // Wait a bit
        vTaskDelay( TOGGLE_LED_DELAY_MS);

        //
        // Turn off the LED.
        //
        GPIOPinWrite(GPIO_PORTN_BASE, GPIO_PIN_0, 0x0);

        // Wait a bit
        vTaskDelay( TOGGLE_LED_DELAY_MS );
    }
}

uint32_t g_ui32SysClock;

void prvSetupHardware()
{
    // Configure PLL
    g_ui32SysClock = SysCtlClockFreqSet((SYSCTL_XTAL_25MHZ |
                                         SYSCTL_OSC_MAIN |
                                         SYSCTL_USE_PLL |
                                         SYSCTL_CFG_VCO_480), 120000000);
    //
    // Enable the GPIO port that is used for the on-board LED.
    //
    SysCtlPeripheralEnable(SYSCTL_PERIPH_GPION);

    //
    // Check if the peripheral access is enabled.
    //
    while(!SysCtlPeripheralReady(SYSCTL_PERIPH_GPION))
    {
    }

    //
    // Enable the GPIO pin for the LED (PN0).  Set the direction as output, and
    // enable the GPIO pin for digital function.
    //
    GPIOPinTypeGPIOOutput(GPIO_PORTN_BASE, GPIO_PIN_0);
}
```

- Edit `tm4c1294ncpdt_startup_ccs_gcc.c`: add the following lines after the line containing `static void IntDefaultHandler(void);`

```c
extern void xPortPendSVHandler(void);
extern void vPortSVCHandler(void);
extern void xPortSysTickHandler(void);
```

The resulting code should look like:

```c
void ResetISR(void);
static void NmiSR(void);
static void FaultISR(void);
static void IntDefaultHandler(void);

extern void xPortPendSVHandler(void);
extern void vPortSVCHandler(void);
extern void xPortSysTickHandler(void);
```

- Edit `tm4c1294ncpdt_startup_ccs_gcc.c`:  replace the default interrupt handler by the FreeRTOS one in array `g_pfnVectors[]`.
  Original code:

```c
  void (* const g_pfnVectors[])(void) =
{
    (void (*)(void))((uint32_t)pui32Stack + sizeof(pui32Stack)),
                                            // The initial stack pointer
    ResetISR,                               // The reset handler
    NmiSR,                                  // The NMI handler
    FaultISR,                               // The hard fault handler
    IntDefaultHandler,                      // The MPU fault handler
    IntDefaultHandler,                      // The bus fault handler
    IntDefaultHandler,                      // The usage fault handler
    0,                                      // Reserved
    0,                                      // Reserved
    0,                                      // Reserved
    0,                                      // Reserved
    IntDefaultHandler,                      // SVCall handler
    IntDefaultHandler,                      // Debug monitor handler
    0,                                      // Reserved
    IntDefaultHandler,                      // The PendSV handler
    IntDefaultHandler,                      // The SysTick handler
```

Resulting code:

```c
void (* const g_pfnVectors[])(void) =
{
    (void (*)(void))((uint32_t)pui32Stack + sizeof(pui32Stack)),
                                            // The initial stack pointer
    ResetISR,                               // The reset handler
    NmiSR,                                  // The NMI handler
    FaultISR,                               // The hard fault handler
    IntDefaultHandler,                      // The MPU fault handler
    IntDefaultHandler,                      // The bus fault handler
    IntDefaultHandler,                      // The usage fault handler
    0,                                      // Reserved
    0,                                      // Reserved
    0,                                      // Reserved
    0,                                      // Reserved
    vPortSVCHandler,                        // SVCall handler
    IntDefaultHandler,                      // Debug monitor handler
    0,                                      // Reserved
    xPortPendSVHandler,                     // The PendSV handler
    xPortSysTickHandler,                    // The SysTick handler
```

- Edit the project properties for the GCC Compiler directories, and add the following directories:
   `${workspace_loc:/${ProjName}/FreeRTOS-Kernel/include}`
   `${workspace_loc:/${ProjName}/FreeRTOS-Kernel/portable/GCC/ARM_CM4F}`
   `${workspace_loc:/${ProjName}`
   `${workspace_loc:/${ProjName}/driverlib}`
   and click on the `Apply and close` button.

[image: GCC Compiler include directories]

- Edit `D:\ti\workspace_v10\TM4C129EXL-FreeRTOS\FreeRTOSConfig.h` and delete the following lines:

```c
#define configGENERATE_RUN_TIME_STATS       1
#define portCONFIGURE_TIMER_FOR_RUN_TIME_STATS()                              \
                                            g_vulRunTimeStatsCountValue = 0ul
#define portGET_RUN_TIME_COUNTER_VALUE()    g_vulRunTimeStatsCountValue
```

- Edit the GCC compiler Command-line pattern and add the `-mfloat-abi=hard` option  after `${flags}` in the Command-line pattern:
  `${command} ${flags} -mfloat-abi=hard  ${output_flag}${output} ${inputs}`

[image: GCC Compiler Command-line pattern]

- Edit the GNU Linker Command-line pattern and add the `-mfloat-abi=hard` option after `${flags}`:>br/>
  `${command} ${flags} -mfloat-abi=hard  ${output_flag}${output} ${inputs}`

[image: GCC linker Command-line pattern]

- Edit the GCC Linker libraries: add `libdriver.a` to the `-l` option, and `${workspace_loc:/${ProjName}/driverlib}` to the `-L` option, then click on the `Apply and close` button.

[image: GCC linker libraries options]

- Build your project - it should build without any errors.
- Flash your project by running it.

In my case, I had to stop the project and to press the board `reset`button in order to the program to start.

Finally, the LED should start blinking every 200ms.

The complete list of files in the project once the project 'cleaned' should ultimately be:

```
Folder PATH listing for volume DATA
Volume serial number is 0E12-BCA2
D:.
|   .ccsproject
|   .cproject
|   .project
|   blinky.c
|   FreeRTOSConfig.h
|   main.c
|   tm4c1294ncpdt.lds
|   tm4c1294ncpdt_startup_ccs_gcc.c
|   
+---.settings
|       org.eclipse.cdt.codan.core.prefs
|       org.eclipse.cdt.debug.core.prefs
|       org.eclipse.core.resources.prefs
|       
+---Debug
|   |   ccsObjs.opt
|   |   makefile
|   |   objects.mk
|   |   sources.mk
|   |   subdir_rules.mk
|   |   subdir_vars.mk
|   |   TM4C129EXL-FreeRTOS.map
|   |   
|   +---driverlib
|   |       subdir_rules.mk
|   |       subdir_vars.mk
|   |       
|   \---FreeRTOS-Kernel
|       |   subdir_rules.mk
|       |   subdir_vars.mk
|       |   
|       \---portable
|           +---GCC
|           |   \---ARM_CM4F
|           |           subdir_rules.mk
|           |           subdir_vars.mk
|           |           
|           \---MemMang
|                   subdir_rules.mk
|                   subdir_vars.mk
|                   
+---driverlib
|       adc.h
|       aes.h
|       can.h
|       comp.h
|       cpu.h
|       crc.h
|       debug.h
|       des.h
|       eeprom.h
|       emac.h
|       epi.h
|       flash.h
|       fpu.h
|       gpio.h
|       hibernate.h
|       i2c.h
|       interrupt.h
|       lcd.h
|       libdriver.a
|       mpu.h
|       onewire.h
|       pin_map.h
|       pwm.h
|       qei.h
|       rom.h
|       rom_map.h
|       rtos_bindings.h
|       shamd5.h
|       ssi.h
|       sw_crc.h
|       sysctl.h
|       sysexc.h
|       systick.h
|       timer.h
|       uart.h
|       udma.h
|       usb.h
|       watchdog.h
|       
+---FreeRTOS-Kernel
|   |   croutine.c
|   |   event_groups.c
|   |   list.c
|   |   queue.c
|   |   stream_buffer.c
|   |   tasks.c
|   |   timers.c
|   |   
|   +---include
|   |       atomic.h
|   |       croutine.h
|   |       deprecated_definitions.h
|   |       event_groups.h
|   |       FreeRTOS.h
|   |       list.h
|   |       message_buffer.h
|   |       mpu_prototypes.h
|   |       mpu_wrappers.h
|   |       portable.h
|   |       projdefs.h
|   |       queue.h
|   |       semphr.h
|   |       StackMacros.h
|   |       stack_macros.h
|   |       stdint.readme
|   |       stream_buffer.h
|   |       task.h
|   |       timers.h
|   |       
|   \---portable
|       +---GCC
|       |   \---ARM_CM4F
|       |           port.c
|       |           portmacro.h
|       |           
|       \---MemMang
|               heap_4.c
|               
\---inc
        asmdefs.h
        hw_adc.h
        hw_aes.h
        hw_can.h
        hw_ccm.h
        hw_comp.h
        hw_des.h
        hw_eeprom.h
        hw_emac.h
        hw_epi.h
        hw_fan.h
        hw_flash.h
        hw_gpio.h
        hw_hibernate.h
        hw_i2c.h
        hw_ints.h
        hw_lcd.h
        hw_memmap.h
        hw_nvic.h
        hw_onewire.h
        hw_pwm.h
        hw_qei.h
        hw_shamd5.h
        hw_ssi.h
        hw_sysctl.h
        hw_sysexc.h
        hw_timer.h
        hw_types.h
        hw_uart.h
        hw_udma.h
        hw_usb.h
        hw_watchdog.h
        tm4c1294ncpdt.h
```

Comment: @Omegon: As you are a new user, I would suggest reading this article: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: Hey Frant, Thank you for your quick answer, I didn't knew, that there was a Tiva C example for FreeRTOS. If I try to compile this example I get some weard Errors which I think won't help you to answer my question at this point. Is there anything to know about the compilers which I should use or other reasons for not compiling the example ccs Project?

Comment: @Omegon: Are you using the Windows version of Code Composer Studio or the Linux one ? What is the exact version of Code Composer Studio you attempted to build the FreeRTOS example with ? Is using Code Composer Studio an absolute requirement for your assignment, or just your own personal choice ? Also, you did not answer regarding the version of FreeRTOS you are supposed to use: this is a very important information, since the demo is using FreeRTOS 7.0.2 from what I remember.

Comment: Thanks for the really good answer, CCS is a requirement and im using 10.1 Version. The RTOS Version doesn't really matter I think. I'll try your instructions and I will add a Comment here. Thank you.

Comment: @Omegon: Any updates ? thanks.

Comment: @Frant I was trying the same project on the TM4C123GXL, FreeRTOS version v202212.00 & CSS 12.6.0. When I try to build the project I get an error "free2.out section `.bss' will not fit in region SRAM'`. I changed the size of the SRAM in the 'tm4c123gh6pm.lds' file, that allows me to build but when I flash/debug it just stalls. any suggestions?